# Python - Seaborn grid shows, but no content (image) is showing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm very new to python, and recently started learning seaborn. When I ran the code, there was no track back and the grid was showed up in a new window. But the problem was no image showed for the FaceGrid, the distplot was showning. Not sure what happened, really appreciate if anyone could help me! Thnank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
train["Age"] = train["Age"].fillna(train["Age"].median())

#THIS ONE IS NOT SHOWN
sns.FacetGrid(train, col='Survived', row='Pclass', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)

#THIS ONE WAS SHOWED
sns.distplot(train['Age'])

sns.plt.show()
```

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Iqw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) it appears that calling sns.FacetGrid initializes the grid. After that you need to map plots onto the grid. Hopefully that helps.